# How can I mint a non-transferrable token using Token-2022 in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, token-2022

How do I mint a non-transferrable token using [Token 2022](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022) using JS/TS (eg `@metaplex-foundation/js` or similar).

Right now I use `@metaplex-foundation/js` to run:

```
const createOutput = await metaplexNFTs.create({
  uri: "https://arweave.net/123",
  name: someName,
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0, 
})
```

Though I'm happy to use raw `@solana/spl-token` if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It roughly boils down to:

```
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    Connection,
    Keypair,
    SystemProgram,
    Transaction,
} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
    createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction,
    createInitializeMintInstruction,
    getAccountLen,
    getMintLen,
    ExtensionType,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
} from '../src';

// create the mint
    const mintAuthority = Keypair.generate();
    const decimals = 9;

    const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
    const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.NonTransferable]);
    const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: mint,
            space: mintLen,
            lamports,
            programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(mint, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(mint, decimals, mintAuthority.publicKey, null, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)
    );
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, mintKeypair], undefined);

// create the token account
        const owner = Keypair.generate();
        const accountLen = getAccountLen([ExtensionType.ImmutableOwner, ExtensionType.NonTransferableAccount]);
        const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(accountLen);

        const sourceKeypair = Keypair.generate();
        const source = sourceKeypair.publicKey;
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: source,
                space: accountLen,
                lamports,
                programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
            }),
            createInitializeImmutableOwnerInstruction(source, TEST_PROGRAM_ID),
            createInitializeAccountInstruction(source, mint, owner.publicKey, TEST_PROGRAM_ID)
        );
        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, sourceKeypair], undefined);

// mint the token
        const amount = 1;
        await mintTo(connection, payer, mint, source, mintAuthority, amount, [], undefined, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);
```

There's a full example of creating the mint at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/examples/nonTransferable.ts, and a full test at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/test/e2e-2022/nonTransferableMint.test.ts